# Bash shorthand for running multiple test-and-or statements

Tags: bash

Suppose I have the following in bash:

```shell
if [[ $cond1 = true ]]; then
  [[ $cond2 = true ]] && echo hello world || echo goodbye cruel world
fi
```

The second line is essentially a shorthand for an if-else statement (unless, of course, the `echo hello world` part fails, in which case the `echo goodbye cruel world` will happen, as well).

Is it possible to combine all three of these lines into one using the shorthand notation?  More generally, is it possible to run a block of commands as a unit?

```shell
# <> and </> denotes some special syntax (tbd) for specifying a block of commands
[[ $cond1 = true ]] && <> [[ $cond2 = true ]] && echo hello world || echo goodbye cruel world </>
```

I suppose I could do something like

```shell
[[ $cond1 = true ]] && eval '[[ $cond2 = true ]] && echo hello world || echo goodbye cruel world'
```

I'm just not a fan of `eval` and needing to escape single quotes and such.

Comment: You could group with `{ ... }`, but at this point I'd really write out all the `if`s, `then`s and `fi`s for clarity.

Comment: Psh.  Clarity.  What kind of coder wants *clarity*. /s   I had tried that, but it turns out I was missing a `;` after the last statement, so it wanted more input.  Thanks!

Comment: Try this `if [[ $cond1 == true && $cond2 == true ]] && echo Hello || echo Goodbye`

Comment: @JoaoVitorino If `$cond1 != true`, I don't want `echo Goodbye` to happen.

Comment: @oguzismail I know.  I was kidding.  About half of my questions on SO are more about learning than about needing a solution.  I'm new to bash.

Answer (score -1):

It's easier with numbers.

```
[ "${cond1}" -eq 1 ] && [ "${cond2}" -eq 1 ] && [ "${cond3}" -eq 1 ] && \
echo "hello world."
```

So yes, it's possible, but it's not very elegant.  I'd probably instead use:-

```
function command1 {
# Do some stuff here
echo "1" > stack
}

function command2 {
# Do some other stuff here
echo "1" > stack
}

function command3 {
# Do some other stuff here
echo "1" > stack
}
```

Then later I can do:-

```
[ $(wc -l stack | cut -d' ' -f1) -eq 3 ] && echo "Hello World!"
```

So that gets the three tests down to one.